# Error installing . install.sh on BTT PITFT50/ v2.0 with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pitft

I am trying to install the . install.sh file and I am getting the error below. I am trying to configure the BTT PITFT50 V2.0 on a raspberry pi and this is the last step in need but is not working.
Please see below and please help. I do not know what else to try.

Thank you.

```
pi@octopi:~ $ . install.sh
Updating system resources ...
[sudo] password for pi:
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
144 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Done.
Installing Dependencies ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fonts-wqy-zenhei' instead of 'ttf-wqy-zenhei'
Note, selecting 'fonts-wqy-zenhei' instead of 'ttf-wqy-zenhei'
fonts-wqy-zenhei is already the newest version (0.9.45-7).
libboost1.58-all-dev is already the newest version (1.58.0+dfsg-5.1+rpi1+b4).
libdbus-1-dev is already the newest version (1.12.20-0+deb10u1).
libfontconfig1-dev is already the newest version (2.13.1-2).
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.58.3-2+deb10u2).
libinput-dev is already the newest version (1.12.6-2+deb10u1).
libjpeg-dev is already the newest version (1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1).
libmtdev-dev is already the newest version (1.1.5-1+b2).
libqt5svg5 is already the newest version (5.11.3-2).
libqt5svg5-dev is already the newest version (5.11.3-2).
libqt5websockets5 is already the newest version (5.11.3-5).
libqt5websockets5-dev is already the newest version (5.11.3-5).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1d-0+deb10u7).
libts-dev is already the newest version (1.19-1).
libudev-dev is already the newest version (241-7~deb10u8+rpi1).
libxkbcommon-dev is already the newest version (0.8.2-1).
python3-pyqt5-dbg is already the newest version (5.11.3+dfsg-1+rpi1+b3).
python3-pyqt5.qtsvg is already the newest version (5.11.3+dfsg-1+rpi1+b3).
qml-module-qtquick-controls2 is already the newest version (5.11.3+dfsg-2).
qt5-default is already the newest version (5.11.3+dfsg1-1+rpi1+deb10u4).
qtcreator is already the newest version (4.8.2-1).
qtdeclarative5-dev is already the newest version (5.11.3-4).
qtsvg5-doc is already the newest version (5.11.3-2).
libgbm-dev is already the newest version (19.3.2-1~bpo10+1~rpt4).
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (19.3.2-1~bpo10+1~rpt4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
Check GLdriver ...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
Done.
Set render ...
Adding user pi to group render
Done.
Setting Permissions ...
-bash: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf: Permission denied
-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
Done.
Setting up Sudo for wifi configuration...
cp: cannot stat 'OctoBTT/OctoBTT.sudoers.d': No such file or directory
Done.
Password: raspberrysu: Authentication failure
Setting up Autostart ...
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
gpu_mem=256
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
# enable raspicam
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
Done.
Connection to 192.168.0.105 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.0.105 closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The important info is here:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

You should urn the script as root (`sudo . install.sh` / `sudo bash install.sh`).
The error can also happen if there's another process running `apt install`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried what you suggested, and it did not work. Please see below.
pi@octopi:~ $ (sudo . install.sh)
[sudo] password for pi:
sudo: .: command not found
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo . install.sh
sudo: .: command not found
pi@octopi:~ $ (sudo.install / sudo bash install.sh)
-bash: sudo.install: command not found
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo.install / sudo bash install.sh
-bash: sudo.install: command not found
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo . install / sudo bash install.sh
sudo: .: command not found

Comment: try just `sudo bash install.sh`